# C: Summing values < 0 in multi-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays

```
for(day=0; day<NUMDAYS; day++) {
    for(period=0; period<NUMPERIODS; period++) {
      if(mood[period][day]<0)
      sum++;
    }
}
printf("Total number of days less than 0 is: \n", sum);
```

/* I am writing a program that is a multi-dimensional array (3x4) and I am inputting values between -5 thru 5.  The code is supposed to count the number of days(columns) that have and period(rows) with values less that 0.  Every time I attempt to execute the code, I get nothing */

Answer (score 1):

It's because you don't actually *print* the value. The [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) function requires you to specify the values you want to print in the format string, like e.g.

```
printf("Total number of days less than 0 is: %d\n", sum);
```

Note that `"%d"` at the end of the string, which indicates that `printf` should get an `int` argument and print it as decimal.

Comment: If I initialized sum to be a float 'float sum = 0.0' would the '%d\n' then become '%lf\n' ? Thank you!

Comment: @akloady252 `"%f"` would be enough.

Comment: @joachim_pileobrg, I am getting an output, but it is an out put that does not make sense.  For instance, if I use that values of  [[1,2,3},(2,3,4},[3,4,5],{-3,4,5}] for my 3x4 array, I get 'Total number of days less that 0 is: 16'.

Comment: @akloady252 And you do initialize `sum` to zero before the loop?

Comment: @joachim_pileborg, that was it.  Thank you so much for your assistance.  It's my first experience with programming; ever.